# White's 'aggressive' attack after Sic. defense opening

Tags: strategy

Searching for the Mackenzie(?) or Mcallister (?) attack: White King’s pawn opening led to good center control with Bishop and both Rooks at d1 and e1.

Can’t the replay on Chess.com because I wasn’t signed in. I did beat a Masters level computer game.

Comment: Any other details? Did it arise out of a Najdorf, Dragon, etc.?

Comment: Returning to chess after many years. The computer identified my ‘strategy’ as something-like the “McK…. or McAll.,.... Attack”. I know that Black was on defense most of the game by happenstance. Trying to remember some of the positioning, such as both rooks at d1 and e1.
 
‘Endgame’ (?) : used my Knights in d6 and e8 area and Queen d8 for the ‘mate’ sequence. 
The ‘Avatar’ (MasterLevel) said it never in check before ( Never?)  And that I should give his kids lessons;must’ve been following some ‘grand’ plan  that I was unaware of  :)

Comment: Remembering my early openinng moves:  pe4...pg4...B b5 (took blacks night eventual)

Comment: As a side note, the comments by your bot (and the fact that it was a bot you can play when you aren't signed in) seem to indicate it was Emir. Emir is not master level, being rated 1000. Master would be 2200.

Answer (score 2):

There's an opening that's called "Ruy López Opening: Morphy Defense, Mackenzie Variation" but it only partially fits your description. It goes like this:

```
[FEN ""]
1.e4 e5 2.Nf3 Nc6 3.Bb5 a6 4.Ba4 Nf6 5.d4
```

It does have e4 and Bb5, but it has d4 instead of g4.

Comment: I'll look at this set up!! Lopez. Great. Thanks D M
BTW.. as a guest on Chess--- i just checked ---I was playing Noam...not Emir in Internediate...unless they rotate bots. But Noam is in Master showing 2200.

Comment: Noam is a master, yes, but Emir is the one who makes comments about never having been in check before and teaching his kids. They're both available without registering. In that case, congrats on beating a master.

Comment: Thanks. At 78,  I aporeciate  your 'congrats'.